# Parallel processing module in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-module

I have a high CPU usage code in Python that I want to split among cores so that the code is completed faster, e.g.

```
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        for k in range(1000):
            for l in range(1000):
                print i, j, k, l
```

The script will have to run a trillion times on a single core. Which module in Python would allow be to run the processes parallel on multiple cores and how? I have seen some other answers but what would be the easiest way to split the above code among 8 cores?

Comment: what other answers have you seen?

Comment: and do you want to "split" the above code to 8 cores or just have 8 cores do that same work? Because I don't see anything in your code that can be "split" up really.

Comment: Your example of `print i, j, k, l` doesn't look quite paralellizable ;)

Comment: @shafeen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842237/parallel-processing-in-python

Comment: @shafeen split the code among 8 cores.

Comment: Your example is not very useful. The loops are to arbitrary to give a proper answer. Please look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers for e.g. parallel mapping. Also never forget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law.

Comment: Good news: 1000 / 8 = 125, so you can run a thread on each core with i in the ranges [0,125), [125,250), [250,375), ... , [875, 1000). Bad news: there's only one console to print to.