# execute parallel command in python

Tags: python, command-line, parallel-processing

I'm trying to execute multiple linux commands using Python.
Currently my script is

```
    import os
    os.system('cmd1')
    os.system('cmd2')
    os.system('cmd3')
    os.system('cmd4')
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to execute cmd1 and cmd2 in parallel. After cmd1 and cmd2 finishes, the system will execute cmd3 and cmd4?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: More to the point, your browser search should have given you a hit for the [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842237/parallel-processing-in-python#3846686) package.

Comment: Actually, [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) should also work and be enough to spawn them in parallel. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743838/python-subprocess-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

Use os.fork() and run the two system commands in two children.  Use os.waitpid() on the two children before executing cmd3.