# Grid computing for python3 program

Tags: python-3.x, grid-computing

I'm performing python computation and today I whant to use ressources from different computer (cpu, ram, and maybe gpu) from one computer.

After some research it seems it is called  "grid computing" or "grid desktop". Are there linux distribution or reference free software to do that with python programs? I heard about "DIET" grid software, but I don't know if this is what I'm looking for.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [parallel computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python) in Python (potentially many machines, many cores)?

Or maybe [multi-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842237/parallel-processing-in-python) in Python (single machine, all cores)?

Grid computing is a term you hear less and less nowadays but the above questions and their anwers will give you a clue to the direction of search.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is parallel computing, dispatched on different computers. I used

Comment: But i wasn't seeing how to dispatched it. I found a toolbox named "ray". It looks corresponding