# Alternative to Nested Loop and a funtion inside it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time-complexity, nested-loops

I want to upgrade my code since the algorithm takes 17hours to compute. I tried several methods but did not work. could you please suggest me any alternative of the code in order to save time?

%%time

```
# test algorithm1 - fuzzy
matched_pair = []
for x in dataset1['full_name_eng']:
    for y in dataset2['name']:
        if (fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x,y) > 85):
            matched_pair.append((x,y))
            print((x,y))
```

I am comparing names from 2 dataset columns and find the matched pair.

Comment: The complexity of this is currently around O(dataset1^dataset2). Could you use a search tree instead?

Comment: I want to compare each name to each name in different columns and how can I use the search tree here?

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Is most of the time spent on the fuzz function or the rest?

Comment: Probably use something like Dask dataframes instead of pandas. Has a similar API, but you can more easily process the data in parallel.

Comment: If you really want to compare all then you end up for huge amount of operations which takes time. And probably that fuzzy compare is a complex thing to do. One approach would be save pairs which you have compared earlier to a database and first try to search result from there.

Comment: Just to make sure.... do you have python-Levenshtein installed?

Comment: yes I have installed

Comment: @GuramKeretchashvili Sorry... I thought you were looking through a database instead.

Comment: What exactly does `token_sort_ratio` do? It may be possible to order `dataset2['name']` in such a way that once you find one pair `x,y` that doesn't meet the threshold, then you can terminate the inner loop early.

Comment: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x,y) this funtion just returns the number (similarity of 2 strings)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to introduce parallel processing.  Currently this is single-threaded code so is probably not using all the CPU resources available.  If you have 4 or 8 cores you should see a significant improvement from spreading the calculation over all of them.

I don't have much experience with this in Python. Here's an intro on one approach:
[Parallel Processing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842237/parallel-processing-in-python)

In your case, you might want to write a function that compares a single value with each value in `y`.  Then map that function over `x` using the parallel-processing framework.